# R XTS package to.minutes3

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I try am trying to use the "to.minutes3" function in the xts package to segment my data.

This function does correctly put the time column into the desired intervals. But data columns becomes "open" , "close", "high" and "low". Is there are way tell the function to average the data points that fall into the same interval?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `period.apply`.  Assuming your data are in object `x` and are *more* frequent than 3-minutes, the code below will give you a mean for each distinct, non-overlapping, 3-minute interval.

```
> period.apply(x, endpoints(x,k=3,"minutes"), mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the answer is no, without completely changing that function, based on help("to.period").  `to.minutes` uses `to.period`, which says the following w.r.t. the OHLC parameter:

> OHLC   should an OHLC object be
>   returned? (only OHLC=TRUE currently
>   supported)

So other return values aren't supported.